# how to rotate gauge needle according to outcome values?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, image-rotation, gauge

I am a newbie and I want to use [this example](https://github.com/Paroca72/sc-widgets/blob/master/raw/sc-arcgauge/indicator.md) (example number 3) in my app.

My app will do some calculations at background and the result will be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. How should I make the needle move accordingly (needle should move left to right)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output, you could use the code from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWCHDoO14aE to rotate the needle image a certain number of degrees to get to the value on the gauge

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try but it must work. change stroke_colors attr as below to get proper coloring as in your image above. There are seven color segments so 1 segment means max_val/7

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="162dp"
    android:background="#354051">

    <com.sccomponents.widgets.ScArcGauge
        android:id="@+id/gauge"
        xmlns:sc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="30dp"
        sc:scc_angle_start="-180"
        sc:scc_angle_sweep="180"
        sc:scc_stroke_colors="#F7AD36|#8BBE28|#8BBE28|#F7AD36|#F7AD36|#EC4949|#EC4949"
        sc:scc_stroke_colors_mode="solid"
        sc:scc_stroke_size="30dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/indicator"/>

</FrameLayout>
float angle0 = 0;
float angle1 = gauge.percentageToAngle(max_val/7);
float angle2 = gauge.percentageToAngle(max_val/7*3);
float angle3 = gauge.percentageToAngle(max_val/7*5);
float angle4 = gauge.percentageToAngle(max_val);

float angle;

if(cur_val >= 0 && cur_val < max_val/7)
    angle = angle0;
else if(cur_val >= max_val/7 && cur_val < max_val/7*3)
    angle = angle1;
else if(cur_val >= max_val/7*3 && cur_val < max_val/7*5)
    angle = angle2;
else if(cur_val >= max_val/7*5 && cur_val < max_val)
    angle = angle3;
else 
    angle = angle4;


indicator.setRotation(angle);
```